# Accessibility: Voice Over doesn't read anything in a custom nib automatically in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, accessibility, voiceover

I'm trying to do my app more accessible. I have created a custom UIView that is added to the UIViewController using this code:

```
emergenteTiempos *emer = [emergenteTiempos shared:self.view];
[self.view addSubview:emer];
```

This code calls a custom UIView:

[image: My xib file]

I have read in [Making app Accessible](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW9) that you must uncheck the accessibility for container and, in my case, the UIView that contains all elements (UILabel,UIButton), but you must check accessibility for these elements individually. So I did this:

[image: Setting accessibility to elements]

But when the custom view appears in the screen, Voice Over doesn't read anything automatically. I have to press in each element in order to Voice Over says the label of this element.

I want Voice Over pronounces all the fields automatically when the view appears. I have tried many things, such as:

```
@implementation MultiFacetedView
- (NSArray *)accessibleElements
{
   if ( _accessibleElements != nil )
   {
      return _accessibleElements;
   }
   _accessibleElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   /* Create an accessibility element to represent the first contained element and initialize it as a component of MultiFacetedView. */
   UIAccessibilityElement *element1 = [[[UIAccessibilityElement alloc] initWithAccessibilityContainer:self] autorelease];

   /* Set attributes of the first contained element here. */
   [_accessibleElements addObject:element1];

   /* Perform similar steps for the second contained element. */
   UIAccessibilityElement *element2 = [[[UIAccessibilityElement alloc] initWithAccessibilityContainer:self] autorelease];

   /* Set attributes of the second contained element here. */
   [_accessibleElements addObject:element2];

   return _accessibleElements;
}

/* The container itself is not accessible, so MultiFacetedView should return NO in isAccessiblityElement. */
- (BOOL)isAccessibilityElement
{
   return NO;
}

/* The following methods are implementations of UIAccessibilityContainer protocol methods. */
- (NSInteger)accessibilityElementCount
{
   return [[self accessibleElements] count];
}

- (id)accessibilityElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
   return [[self accessibleElements] objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (NSInteger)indexOfAccessibilityElement:(id)element
{
   return [[self accessibleElements] indexOfObject:element];
}
@end
```

But Voice Over doesn't read anything automatically.

Could you help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you found out a solution ?